# Cardioid-looking curve, does it have a name?

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, terminology, curves

The curve, given in polar coordinates as $r(\theta)=\sin(\theta)/\theta$
is plotted below.
[image: cardioid-looking curve]

This is similar to the classical cardioid, but it is not the same curve (the curve above is not even algebraic, I believe). Does this curve have a name? Does it show up somewhere?
This curve has the property that it solves $\mathrm{Im}(1/z+\log(z))=0$, if this perhaps rings a bell.

This particular curve arises in some research I am working on at the moment, and it would be great if it perhaps connects to some classical area.

**Edit:** Thanks for the great references!
As a reward, here is a more artistic rendering of the shape
using a type of complex dynamical systems.
[image: Nice cardiodid]

Comment: Check mathcurve.com.  At least 100 named curves.

Comment: That was a great resource!

Comment: For people too lazy to type, and because I like the enthusiasm of the name, a clickable version of @skbmoore's [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371750/cardioid-looking-curve-does-it-have-a-name#comment940155_371750):  [Encyclopédie des formes mathématiques remarquables](https://mathcurve.com).

Comment: It seems to be a limacon.

Comment: @user165496 ---   the limaçon has a different equation, in particular it lacks the infinite series of windings that the cochleoid has: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limaçon

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The name of the curve is [cochleoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochleoid) (= shell-shaped rather than *cardioid* = heart-shaped).

I compare the two below (gold = cochleoid, blue = cardioid). The distinction shell/heart refers to the additional windings remarked upon by მამუკა ჯიბლაძე , without these windings the two shapes would be qualitatively the same.

[image]

Comment: On [Encyclopédie des formes mathématiques remarquables](https://mathcurve.com), which @skbmoore [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371750/cardioid-looking-curve-does-it-have-a-name#comment940155_371750):  https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d/cochleoid/cochleoid.shtml

Answer (score 33):

Not an answer - just want to note that the curve has more hidden branches. They can be seen looking at the parametric equation
$$
x=\frac{\sin(\varphi)}\varphi,\quad y=\frac{1-\cos(\varphi)}\varphi
$$
where $\varphi=2\theta$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From what LSpice and skbmoore shared https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d/cochleoid/cochleoid.shtml,
There's this illustration of a helix on a cylinder[image]
The picture in the middle is the view when lined up with the side of the cylinder. If I understand the site correctly, the line traced by the helix in this perspective is a cochleoid.

Comment: This is indeed true: say,$$x=t+\cos(t),y=-\sin(t),z=1+t$$is a helix, and projecting it from the point $(1,0,1)$ to the plane $z=0$ gives$$(\frac{1-\cos(t)}t,\frac{\sin(t)}t,0).$$Explicitly, to project you must send $(x,y,z)$ to $((x-z)/(1-z),y/(1-z),0)$; then just substitute the above parametric expressions for $t$.